# Graphic designing for support all sizes of IPhone/IPad products

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, graphics

it's been a while since my last post.

This question might be a lazy question but I am having a hard time finding good resources/advices on how graphics/images are done/created to support all sizes of iPhone (4, 4s, 5, 5s, 6, 6+) and at the same time iPad (mini, 2).

For example I have this raw image from Photoshop or GIMP or even Paint (if it could support it), should I export that image to different sizes (1x, 2x, or even 3x)? The question of this thread is how?

Answer (score 0):

Make a standard image at 1x. for everything else mentioned above other than 6+, use x2. For 6+, use x3.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html